# youtube_dl ERROR: requested format not available

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl

Code:

```py
import tempfile
import youtube_dl

link = "https://www.reddit.com/r/CatastrophicFailure/comments/mhqgso/industrial_fire_in_volendam_netherlands_3132021/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3"

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    settings = {
        'verbose': True,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'format': 'best',
        'outtmpl': f'{tempdir}/%(id)s.%(ext)s'
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(settings) as ytdl:
        meta = ytdl.extract_info(
            link,
            download=True
        )
```

Error:

```
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs utf-8, out utf-8, pref cp1252
[debug] youtube-dl version 2021.03.31
[debug] Python version 3.8.5 (CPython) - Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f, ffprobe git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[RedditR] mhqgso: Downloading JSON metadata
[Reddit] hlrzahmcqiq61: Downloading m3u8 information
[Reddit] hlrzahmcqiq61: Downloading MPD manifest
ERROR: requested format not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 806, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 838, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 909, in process_ie_result
    return self.process_ie_result(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 872, in process_ie_result
    return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1674, in process_video_result
    raise ExtractorError('requested format not available',
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: requested format not available
```

Why am I getting this error? I know that the format `'best'` is should work looking at the [docs](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection) and I don't know if I am missing something stupid here.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the reason for the error is to do with the link (URL) than the video format. The URL does not point to a video but to a reddit page that displays the video along with other things.

I am not sure how to use youtube-dl with reddit videos or if that is even an option. However, a quick look at **Page info > Media** in my Waterfox (a Firefox based browser) showed the direct URL to the video as https://v.redd.it/hlrzahmcqiq61/DASH_96.mp4 which can saved using the "save as" button.